# Are subsets of open sets open?

Tags: general-topology

An open set has all its points as interior points,so every point of the open set would have a neighbourhood contained in the set. So a subset of the open set by virtue of having all its points in the open set would also have a neighbourhood for each of its points such that the neighbourhood is contained in the subset and hence the subset is open. How is this hypothesis?

Comment: @Grimmjaw This hypothesis is wrong. Take a single point as the subset of an open set.

Comment: You may consider for instance the set $(-2,2)$, it is open but has a closed subset $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Slugger What has $[-1,1]$ being closed to do with anything?

Comment: *so every point of the open set would have a neighbourhood contained in the set. So a subset of the open set by virtue of having all its points in the open set would also have a neighbourhood* --- When you pass to a (proper) subset, you're omitting points from the original open set, and some of those omitted points might prevent the "would also have a neighborhood" from being true (since the proposed neighborhood would be missing those omitted points).

Answer (score 3):

The set $[-1,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a non-open subset of the open set $(-2,2)$.

Comment: I think this is a misleading answer. it's true that $[-1,1]$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$, but the reason is *not* that it's closed in $\mathbb{R}$. in a topological space there are sets that are both open and closed. (for example, $\mathbb{R}$ is both an open and a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I simply don't understand your comment.  Of course, both the OP and I know well that there are open and closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  The question, however, centered on subsets, and my simple example (which I later saw was in a comment) provides an answer.

Comment: I don't think you should assume that the OP "knows well" there are clopen subsets of $\mathbb{R}$; they are clearly a beginner to topology, and it is a *really* common point of confusion for beginners that "closed" and "open" are not antonyms. personally I don't think you should mention that $[-1,1]$ is closed, which is irrelevant, and instead say "the subset $[-1,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a non-open subset of the open set $(-2,2)$". in my opinion, the way your answer reads, it seems to imply that $[-1,1]$ is non-open because it is closed, which (as you know) is not the case

Comment: hi David. I've taken the liberty of editing your post along the lines I suggested; feel free to rollback if you disagree, but I really strongly think it's an important confusion to avoid for beginners